# How the order_updates property can avoid deadlocks in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

As per [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html), the details for the property `hibernate.order_updates` is given as follows:

> Forces Hibernate to order SQL updates by the primary key value of the
>   items being updated. This will result in fewer transaction deadlocks
>   in highly concurrent systems. e.g. true | false

So by setting this property to false, how the deadlocks can occur. Please help me in understanding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A deadlock might occur when transaction 1 updates row 1 and transaction 2 updates row 2 at the same time. Now transaction 1 wants to update row 2, but has to wait for transaction 2 to complete, since it is holding the write lock. Now if transaction 2 would want to update row 1, it would have to wait for transaction 1, since it is holding that lock, and the deadlock occurs.

As you will notice this happens because the transaction use reverse order for updates (transaction 1 first row 1 then row 2 and transaction 2 first row 2 then row 1). Using this property, you can force hibernate to always order in the same way and the situation as described cannot occur.